# Secondary featured image as div background

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that in wordpress it is possible to use a featured image as the background of a div using the following code

```
background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?>');
```

The question is: is there a way to use a secondary image as a background for this div?

I am using the [Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) and I can display the secondary image with the code bellow

```
<?php 
 
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : 
 
MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image', NULL,  'secondary-featured-thumbnail');
 
endif;
 
?>
```

But is it possible to use this image as bakground?
I wanna something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leLbC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to get the URL of the secondary image, not the full post thumbnail.

In the documentation there is `MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');`

https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

So then on your page, you can do (Not the nicest):

```
    <?php 
 
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : 
 
image_url = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');
?>
<style>
.myclass{
background-image: url('<?php echo image_url ?>');

}
</style>
 <?php 
endif;
 
?>
```

Or you can add that image_url to the html div container:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo image_url ?>');">
</div>
```

Depends on how you have it setup